# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: library.model.Person

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've been struggling with this all day but haven't yet found a solution.

I have a simple entity mapping to a database table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

// Attributes.    
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length=50)      
private String name;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS", nullable = false, length=100)
private String address;

@Column(name = "TELEPHONE", nullable = false, length=10)
private String telephone;

@Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length=50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")   
private List<Book> books;

// Constructors.
public Person() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.name = ("");
    this.address = ("");
    this.telephone = ("");
    this.email = ("");
    this.books = null;
}
```

This entity is governed by a Spring controller with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, 
                   BindingResult bindingResult, 
                   SessionStatus sessionStatus,
                   Model model /* , 
                   HttpSession session */) throws DAOException {                  
    logger.info(PersonController.class.getName() + ".post() method called.");

    personValidator.validate(person, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    else {

        // Write Person to database.
        personService.insert(person);

        // Set view.
        sessionStatus.setComplete();             
        return "options";            
    }
}
```

The service class is:

```
@Service("personService")
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

@Autowired 
PersonDAO personDAO;

public void insert(Person person) throws DAOException {
    personDAO.insert(person);
}
```

And the DAO is as follows:

```
@Repository("PersonDAO")
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class.getName()); 

@Override
public void insert(Person person) throws DAOException {
    logger.info(PersonDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".insert() method called.");

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        session.save(person);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And of course the part of my Spring servlet binding everything together:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class ">thread</prop>

           <!-- What to do with the database schema. -->
           <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>    
           <!-- validate:    validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
                update:      update the schema.
                create:      creates the schema, destroying previous data.
                create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session. -->                 
        </props>            
    </property>                    
</bean>
```

So why am I getting the message:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: library.model.Person
```

If I try things like:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="library.model" /> 

<property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>library.model.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

At the moment I am getting:

> Jun 15, 2014 10:50:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext Jun 15, 2014
>   10:51:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: library.services.PersonService
>   library.controller.PersonController.personService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: library.dao.PersonDAOImpl
>   library.services.PersonService.personDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'PersonDAOImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4681)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5184)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5179)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Need more of the stack trace.  Usually when I see something like this its a subtle typo.

Comment: Is the name of the table actually `Person` or is it `person` ?

Comment: The table is called Person in the application: it is called PERSON in the database. @Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>library.model.Person</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

With:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
       <value>library.model</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

In your sessionFactory properties.

If you get an error saying the property "packagesToScan" could not be found then you should add the spring-orm library to your project.  If you're using maven then you can add:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>YOUR SPRING VERSION HERE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've tried what you said but I know have an error:

`Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean'

Comment: Are the Spring ORM jars definitely on the class path when you run the application and you're still using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` as the session factory?

Comment: It#s a NetBeans project so all of the .jar files are in their own lib folder as part of the project itself. So yes.

Comment: If it can't find the class, that's usually a classpath problem.  Not sure what you're using to run it, but can you check where it deploys application libraries and ensure that they're in the expected location ?  Alternatively if everything is packaged in a war, make sure that the spring libs are in the war.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the libraries are fine because the wretched application is nor compiling but giving me an error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: library.model.Person.So surely it's in the mapping in the hibernate XML.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` anywhere in the servlet-context.xml?

Comment: Yes. But I'm currently using  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

Comment: If I use <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> and have code <property name="packagesToScan">..., I have the problem wher ethe table isn't recognised.

Comment: With the change I suggested?  Doing some reading and regarding `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, it can't find that class because it was removed in Hibernate 4, so doesn't exist.

Comment: I added: `<property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>library.model</value>                
            </list>
        </property>' to the sessionFactory settings.

Comment: I am grateful. Thanks Matt Wilson.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I am also glad-) Handwriting all the DAO code and servlets is so much easier.